# Avoid casting when using generics

Tags: java, generics

In a project, I have a service and a class using that service. In this example case a repair service that will be used by vehicles. A repair service can only repair a certain type of vehicle: The garage can only repair cars. I need a method in the vehicle to repair it with an applicable service, `repairUsingService(..)`.

My goal is to have a clean `Vehicle` base class and clean `RepairService` implementations. I have tried two ways of designing the `repair` method of the repair service:

- `repair(Vehicle<T> vehicle)`: This is ugly because implementations would need to do `repair(Vehicle<Car> car)` but it is obvious that a car is a vehicle.
- `repairSimple(T vehicle)`: Is nice with that but cannot be called from the `Vehicle` class without an ugly cast.

**Is there a way to avoid casting but still only use the generic parameter type `T`** (like in `repairSimple(T)`)**?**

```
public class Vehicle<T extends Vehicle<T>> {

    public void repairUsingService(RepairService<T> obj) {
        obj.repair(this);
        obj.repairSimple((T) this);
    }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle<Car> {
}

public interface RepairService<T extends Vehicle<T>> {

    void repair(Vehicle<T> vehicle);

    void repairSimple(T vehicle);
}

public class Garage implements RepairService<Car> {
    @Override
    public void repair(Vehicle<Car> car) {
        System.out.println("Car repaired.");
    }

    @Override
    public void repairSimple(Car car) {
        System.out.println("Car repaired.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a real reason for `class Vehicle<T extends Vehicle<T>>` and therefore `class Car extends Vehicle<Car>` instead of just `class Car extends Vehicle` ?

Comment: Cant you do something with just the base class and then override it in an implementing class?

Comment: @MikeNakis It's for methods and variables like `repairUsingService(RepairService<T>)` that need to have the generic type of the vehicle. Or is there a good way to avoid that?

Comment: The `class Vehicle<T extends Vehicle<T>>` construct is a highly advanced and extremely rarely used construct implemented only by veteran programmers who usually try it for a while and then more often than not decide that it was a bad idea after all, and revert to something far simpler.

Comment: 99.9999% of the cases are handled with a simple `class Car extends Vehicle` construct.  If what you are trying to do seems impossible without `class Vehicle<T extends Vehicle<T>>` then most chances are that there is something funny in what you are trying to accomplish, or in what you think you need to do in order to accomplish it.

Comment: @MikeNakis Ok, so if I need a method `setRepairService(RepairService)` in `Vehicle`, how would I ensure that only `RepairService`s that can repair cars are allowed if I use a simple `class Car extends Vehicle` without needing every subclass to override a method?

Answer (score 5):

Could you use this implementation? This way both the vehicle knows, what repair service can repair it, and the service knows, what vehicles it can repair.

```
public interface RepairService<T extends Vehicle<?>> {
    public void repair(T vehicle);
}

public interface Vehicle<T extends RepairService<?>> {
    public void repairUsingService(T service);
}

public class Car implements Vehicle<Garage> {
    @Override
    public void repairUsingService(Garage service) {
    }
}

public class Garage implements RepairService<Car>{
    @Override
    public void repair(Car vehicle) {
    }
}

public class AuthorizedGarage extends Garage {

}


public class Train implements Vehicle<TrainDepot> {
    @Override
    public void repairUsingService(TrainDepot service) {

    }

}

public class TrainDepot implements RepairService<Train> {
    @Override
    public void repair(Train vehicle) {

    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // this works:
        new Car().repairUsingService(new Garage());
        new Train().repairUsingService(new TrainDepot());

        // and this works
        new Garage().repair(new Car());
        new TrainDepot().repair(new Train());

        // but this does not (which is ok)
        //new Garage().repair(new Train());
        //new Car().repairUsingService(new TrainDepot()); 

        // this also works
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add(new Car());
        cars.get(0).repairUsingService(new Garage());

        // this also works, if you have an expensive car ;)
        new Car().repairUsingService(new AuthorizedGarage());

    }

}
```

You could even have a base class for all your repair services to avoid code repetition:

```
public abstract class BaseRepairService<T extends Vehicle<?>> implements 
RepairService<T> {

    @Override
    public void repair(T vehicle) {

    }

}
```

Then your Garage would extend a BaseRepairService with a Car type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to ask the subclass for itself:

```java
abstract class Vehicle<T extends Vehicle<T>> {

    public void repairUsingService(RepairService<T> obj) {
        obj.repair(this);
        obj.repairSimple(getThis());
    }
    abstract T getThis();
}

class Car extends Vehicle<Car> {
    @Override
    Car getThis(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me present two reasonable alternatives.

---

The first is a variation of [Gafter's Gadget](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html):

```
public abstract class Vehicle<V extends Vehicle<V>> {
    private boolean validate() {
        Class<?> cls = getClass();
        for(Class<?> sup;
            (sup = cls.getSuperclass()) != Vehicle.class;
            cls = sup
        );
        Type sup = cls.getGenericSuperclass();
        if(!(sup instanceof ParameterizedType))
            return false;
        Type arg = ((ParameterizedType)sup).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        if(!(arg instanceof Class<?>))
            return false;
        return ((Class<?>)arg).isInstance(this);
    }

    protected Vehicle() {
        assert validate() : "somebody messed up";
    }
}
```

Since `Vehicle` is always parameterized by a subclass, it's OK to use this idiom. During development you run with assertions on and the constructor will throw an error if somebody extends the class incorrectly.

Now the unchecked cast is always safe.

---

The second is that `RepairService` no longer carries a type parameter. Instead, you keep a listing of `Class<? extends Vehicle>` the `RepairService` can repair.

```
public interface RepairService {
    boolean canRepair(Vehicle v);
    // if v can't be repaired, perhaps repair
    // throws an exception or returns boolean instead of void
    void repair(Vehicle v);
}

public class ServiceStation implements RepairService {
    private final List<Class<? extends Vehicle>> types;

    public ServiceStation(Class<? extends Vehicle>... types) {
        this.types = Arrays.asList(types);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRepair(Vehicle v) {
        for(Class<? extends Vehicle> c : types) {
            if(c.isInstance(v))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void repair(Vehicle v) {
        if(!canRepair(v))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        // impl
    }
}
```

At least for the `Vehicle`/`RepairStation` analogy this is probably much more usable than trying to force generics in to the design. `Vehicle` probably doesn't need a type parameter either anymore.

Maybe your actual program is different but you should always consider whether straight program logic solves the problem before introducing a parametric design. Trying to force generics to work in a situation where they are a suboptimal solution gets very awkward.